# PyInstaller icon option doesn't work on Mac

Tags: python, macos, icons, pyinstaller, icns

I ran the following command on my mac and created an .app file.

```
pyinstaller --icon icon.icns --noconsole -n testApp main.py
```

However, the generated .app file does not show the icon.

[image]

icon.icns is specified as an icon file in info.plist.

[image]

The Content/Resouces folder contains icon.icns.

[image]

When I run the .app file, I see an icon on the Dock.

However, the icon is not reflected in the .app file itself. Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried it with a `.ico` file rather than `.icns`?

Comment: Don't use .ico when creating a macOS .app bundle. It's only supported for creating Windows applications with an icon.

Comment: Yes, windows uses `.ico`, macOS uses `.icns`.

Comment: Is it possible that some setting in finder needs tweaking?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You should use the command for creating a macOS app bundle**

If specified correctly, the `icon.icns` will be copied into the Resources folder and applied to the `testApp.app` bundle in the `dist` directory, after running the pyinstaller command. (don't try .ico as suggested, that's for Windows).

I just tried creating a simple Python app using PySide2, and it included the icon file in the app bundle with no problems.

Given that **the icon.icns is in the same directory** as `main.py`:

Your command should be:

`$ pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon icon.icns --name testApp main.py`

This will produce the app bundle, and you should be able to run it just fine.

---

#### But wait, there is even more...

Sadly, the story doesn't quite end here.

**SPOILER:**

To do things "the right way" and make macOS happy, you should also include the:

`--osx-bundle-identifier 'YOUR_IDENTIFIER'`

That way the spec file will include the info for the `Info.plist` file that gets produced.

Also there should be a section in the spec file describing the `Info.plist` contents, something in the lines of:

```
app = BUNDLE(exe,
         name='testApp.app',
         icon='icon.icns',
         bundle_identifier='com.youridentifier',
         info_plist={
            'NSPrincipalClass': 'NSApplication',
            'NSAppleScriptEnabled': False,
            'CFBundleDocumentTypes': [
                {
                    'CFBundleTypeName': 'My File Format',
                    'CFBundleTypeIconFile': 'MyFileIcon.icns',
                    'LSItemContentTypes': ['com.example.myformat'],
                    'LSHandlerRank': 'Owner'
                    }
                ]
            },
         )
```

In the above example, the key/value
`'NSPrincipalClass': 'NSApplication'`
is necessary to allow Mac OS X to render applications using retina resolution.

The key `'NSAppleScriptEnabled'` is assigned the Python boolean False, which will be output to Info.plist as `<false/>`. Finally the key `CFBundleDocumentTypes` tells Mac OS X what file-types your application supports, if any.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 and I've manually awarded the bounty.

Comment: @Legorooj thanks! I'll fill in some more details if the OP cares about it or if he just wants his app to start and display an icon! 

Answer (score -2):

A temporary workaround is to simply Get Info on an .icns file in the Finder; click on and copy the image in the top left of the Get Info window; then paste that .icns image into the same location on the Get Info window of your application.  You can also copy the .icns image from any existing application to any other application by that method.  I believe that functionality has been available on the Mac for well over two decades.  Notwithstanding the above, ultimately it should be coded into the Info.plist contents.  Edit: the .icns image in the Get Info must NOT show a default image. If it does, then open the .icns image in Preview, copy the image and paste it into any Get Info image you desire.  It works for me on my iMac and when copied to two other Macs (Mini 2012 running Mojave 10.14.6 and Mini running El Capitan 10.11.6).

Comment: This would do NOTHING, whatsoever for the purpose of developing an app, that will (hopefully) be running on other people's machines. So this is not a temporary workaround, because if nothing else gets done, it is not working, period. It is a temporary illusion at best.

Comment: It works for me…PERIOD.  On 3 Macs: an iMac running Mojave and when that application is copied to two other Macs:  Mini 2012 running Mojave 10.14.6 and Mini running El Capitan 10.11.6.  When running on those "other people's machines" the app retains the custom icon image on the Finder file, on the Get Info window, and on the Dock.