# How to create shortcut icons for Windows, MacOS and Linux applications bundled with PyInstaller

Tags: python, icons, pyinstaller

I am building a Python application bundled with PyInstaller which is available for Windows, Linux (as AppImage) and MacOS.

I need shortcut icons for those. I have a logo, but I am struggling to bring it to the right format. It seems to me that all three platforms use different icon sizes and formats.

Is there any online/offline generator that allows me to create icons for all three platforms from a jpg file?

Comment: what program language did you use?

Comment: Tags in the questions are quite important. You should really pick bit more than just icons.

Comment: @DoanVanThang I am writing a python application which is distributed as pyinstaller executable (wrapped in an AppImage on Linux)

Comment: Check pyinstaller https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html `icon` parameter, and search for online PNG to ICO, ICNS convertor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned you only need to convert the logo from jpg to icon files for the respective OS, then try image converter of [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org).
This code will generate icon files for all (Mac, Win, Linux)

```
from PIL import Image
filename = r'logo.jpg' # the directory of logo file
img = Image.open(filename) # reads the JPG file

# Generate and save the logo files
img.save('Win_logo.ico')   # On windows, icon file extension is .ico
img.save('Mac_logo.icns')  # On Mac OS, icon file extension is .icns
# Note: Creating icns requires Mac OS
img.save('Linux_logo.png') # in case if your AppImage requires any logo file
```

Optionally, you may specify the icon sizes (for Windows) you want:

```
icon_sizes = [(16,16), (32, 32), (48, 48), (64,64)]
img.save('logo.ico', sizes=icon_sizes)
```

The [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#ico) say that by default it will generate sizes
`[(16, 16), (24, 24), (32, 32), (48, 48), (64, 64), (128, 128), (255, 255)]` and any size bigger than the original size or 255 will be ignored.

check the [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) for more info.

as the Pyinstaller is OS based and ICNS is also generated OS based

### More OS specified

```
from platform import system as OS_Name
os_name = OS_Name()
filename = r'logo.jpg' # the directory of logo file
img = Image.open(filename) # reads the JPG file

# Generate and save the logo files
if os_name == 'Windows': img.save('Win_logo.ico')   # On windows, icon file extension is .ico
if os_name == 'Darwin' : img.save('Mac_logo.icns')  # On Mac OS, icon file extension is .icns
# on Linux the os_name is 'Linux'
img.save('Linux_logo.png') # in case if your AppImage requires any logo file
```

### OS independent for ICNS

The best os independent way is the Online way. [Cloud Convert](https://cloudconvert.com/) is a great tool for that. However, you must convert your `jpg` to `png` first. [Note: Always try to use `png` for logos as they have transparency and more convient]
You may use the Above code's PNG part to auto-convert your JPG to PNG, or use [JPG to PNG](https://cloudconvert.com/jpg-to-png)
Finally convert your PNG file using [PNG to ICNS](https://cloudconvert.com/png-to-icns).

Comment: Need to check if this works, if it does, it is exactly what I am looking for. But you mean img.save('Mac_logo.icns') right? It's a typo, the s is missing in the file extension?

Comment: there are 2 extension `icn` and `icns`, as i don't have a mac, i'm a bit confused now. re-checking...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createicons.py", line 7, in <module>
    img.save('Mac_logo.icns')  # On Mac OS, icon file extension is .icns
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1983, in save
    save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]
KeyError: 'ICNS'

Comment: as i commented in the code [was updated later] Just like pyinstaller, you will need Mac os to create Mac executable file and also the icns file. If you have Mac computer, then it should work file. OS specified stuffs really gives headache to the programmer. checking for any online api and posting new answer for Any OS

Comment: Ah ok - so I'll just do it on mac and should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Tom! I found you the solution!.Go to [here](https://anyconv.com/png-to-icns-converter/) site and convert your image to icns format. Then in pyinstaller run the command:-

```
pyinstaller pythonfile.py -F --i=icon_name.icns -noconsole
```

It works fine.

And if you want to add icon to `python.py` in file in windows then try these:-
**If you are using pygame use this code:-**

```
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

**If you are using TKinter use this code:-**

```
screen = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file = "Any image file")
screen.iconphoto(False, photo)
```

If you want to add icon after your file is completed use **Pyinstaller**:-

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

And in pyinstaller use this command:-

```
pyinstaller pythonfile.py -F --i icon_name.ico -noconsole
```

Some information about it:-

- -F for 1 file so it doesn't create many files. Only 1 which will be the .exe file itself.
- Go to this site for more info [this site](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).
- If you don't use GUI use this command: `pyinstaller pythonfile.py -F --i icon_name.ico -nowindowed`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: And sorry for 2 edits. They were because the things were messed up so.

Comment: Thx for the answer, was asking for how to generate the icon files though

Comment: For that go to this site: https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-ico

Comment: but does this work for all three platforms?

Comment: Please check out my edit answer, does it work? Please reply after trying. Thx

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you just use `auto-py-to-exe`, it uses pyinstaller, but it auto-generates the command, and so you can just upload the image to a GUI

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your PNGs to an ICO format, you could use a PNG to ICO converter (online) like [this](https://cloudconvert.com/png-to-ico). Since all platforms support `.ICO` format files, this would be your one-stop-shop.

The preferred icon size is a square of 96px x 96px (high quality) or 48px x 48px (medium quality).

Also, to set the icon to your application for with pyinstaller, you could specify the path for the icon while creating the installer using the command line.

```sh
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico app.py
```

This would create an installer which contains an application with the specified icon.

Comment: Does Mac OSX really also support these? Thought they need an extra format. Didn't know that.

Comment: @TomAtix Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62607152/13108568) help you?

Comment: so here it says .ico is only for windows, for OSX I need another format... does ico work for linux or do I need another format here as well?

Comment: I think mac natively supports `.icns` files. Linux supports `PNG`, `XPM` and `SVG` formats more [here](https://developer.gnome.org/icon-theme-spec/). For windows, it's `.ico` file. 

I know it's a lot to care about while creating multi-platform applications. But it is how it is...